# nGram partial matching & limiting nGram results in multiple field query

Tags: search, elasticsearch, indexing, n-gram, elasticsearch-2.0

**Background**: I've implemented a partial search on a name field by indexing the tokenized name (`name` field) as well as a trigram analyzed name (`ngram` field).

I've boosted the `name` field to have exact token matches bubble up to the top of the results.

**Problem**: I am trying to implement a query that limits the nGram matches to ones that only match some threshold (say 80%) of the query string.  I understand that `minimum_should_match` seems to be what I am looking for, but my problem is forming the query to actually produce those results.

My exact token matches are boosted to the top but I still get *every* document that has a single matching trigram in the `ngram` field.

[**GIST: Index settings and mapping**](https://gist.github.com/jordancardwell/4fbc488a1d89c6ef40664d31095c0094)

**Index Settings**

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "settings": {
      "index": {
        "number_of_shards": "5",
        "max_result_window": "30000",
        "creation_date": "1475853851937",
        "analysis": {
          "filter": {
            "ngram_filter": {
              "type": "ngram",
              "min_gram": "3",
              "max_gram": "3"
            }
          },
          "analyzer": {
            "ngram_analyzer": {
              "filter": [
                "lowercase",
                "ngram_filter"
              ],
              "type": "custom",
              "tokenizer": "standard"
            }
          }
        },
        "number_of_replicas": "1",
        "uuid": "AuCjcP5sSb-m59bYrprFcw",
        "version": {
          "created": "2030599"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Mappings**

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "my_type": {
        "properties": {
          "acw": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "pcg": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "date": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "dob": {
            "type": "date",
            "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "name": {
            "type": "string",
            "boost": 10
          },
          "ngram": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "ngram_analyzer"
          },
          "bdk": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "mmw": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "mpi": {
            "type": "integer"
          },
          "sex": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Solution Attempts**

[**GIST: Query Attempts**] unlinkifying due to 2 link limit :(
`(https://gist.github.com/jordancardwell/2e690013666e7e1da6ef1acee314b4e6)`

I tried a multi-match query, which gives me correct search results, but I haven't had luck omitting results for names that only match a single trigram (say "**odo**" trigram inside "*the**odo**philus*")

```
//this matches 'frodo' and sends results to the top, since `name` field is boosted
//  but also matches 'theodore' and 'rodolpho'

{
  "size":100,
  "from":0,
  "query":{
    "multi_match":{
      "query":"frodo",
      "fields":[
        "name",
        "ngram"
      ],
      "type":"best_fields"
    }
  }
}
```

.

```
//I then tried to throw in the `minimum_must_match` option
// hoping it would filter out large strings that only had one matching trigram for instance
{
  "size":100,
  "from":0,
  "query":{
    "multi_match":{
      "query":"frodo",
      "fields":[
        "name",
        "ngram"
      ],
      "type":"best_fields",
      "minimum_should_match": "90%",
    }
  }
}
```

I've tried playing around in sense, to manually produce the match queries that this produces to allow me to only apply `minimum_must_match` to the `ngram` field but can't seem to get the syntax right.

```
// I then tried to contruct a custom query to just return the `minimum_should_match`d results on the ngram field
// I started with a query produced by using bodybuilder to `and` and `or` my other search criteria together
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            //each separate field's criteria `must`/`and`ed together
            {
              "query": {
                "bool": {
                  "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                      "should": [
                        //each critereon for a specific field `should`/`or`ed together
                        {
                         //my attempt at getting `ngram` field results.. 
                         // should theoretically only return when field 
                         // contains nothing but matching ngrams 
                         // (i.e. exact matches and other fluke matches)
                          "query": { 
                            "match": {
                              "ngram": {
                                "query": "frodo",
                                "minimum_should_match": "100%"
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                        //... other critereon to be `should`/`or`ed together
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
            //... other criteria to be `must`/`and`ed together
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?**

It seems like this should be fairly straightforward to accomplish, but I must be missing something obvious.

---

### UPDATE

I ran a query with `_explain=true` (using sense UI) to try to understand my results.

I queried for a `match` on the `ngram` field for `"frod"` with `minimum_should_match` = `100%`, yet I still get every record that matches at least one ngram.
(e.g. `rodolpho` even though it doesn't contain `fro`)

[**GIST: test query and results**](https://gist.github.com/jordancardwell/f954be7eb545cab9d482ff135bbc4860)

---

***note**: cross-posted from [discuss.elastic.co]*
will make a link later, can't post more than 2 yet : /

`(https://discuss.elastic.co/t/ngram-partial-match-limiting-ngram-results-in-multiple-field-query/62526)`

Answer (score 1):

I used your settings and mappings to create an index.  And you queries seem to be working fine for me. I would suggest doing an `explain` on one of the "unexpected" documents which is being returned and see why it is being matched and returned with other results.

Here is what I did:

Run the analyze api on your analyzer to see how the query will be split into tokens.

```
curl -XGET 'localhost:9200/my_index/_analyze' -d '
{
  "analyzer" : "ngram_analyzer",
  "text" : "frodo"
}'
```

frodo will be split into 3 tokens with your analyzer.

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "fro",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "rod",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "odo",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

I indexed 3 documents for testing (only used ngrams field) . Here are the docs:

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "ngram": "theodore"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "ngram": "frodo"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "ngram": "rudolpho"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The first query you mentioned, it matches frodo and theodore, but not rudolpho like you mentioned - which makes sense, since rudolpho does not produce any trigrams which match trigrams from frodo

```
frodo -> fro, rod, odo 

rudolpho -> rud, udo, dol, olp, lph, pho
```

Using your second query, I get back only frodo (None of the other two) .

```
{
  "took": 5,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.53148466,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.53148466,
        "_source": {
          "ngram": "frodo"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I then ran an explain (`localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/2/_explain`) on other two docs (theodore and rudolpho) and I see this (I have clipped the response)

```
{
  "_index": "my_index",
  "_type": "my_type",
  "_id": "2",
  "matched": false,
  "explanation": {
    "value": 0,
    "description": "Failure to meet condition(s) of required/prohibited clause(s)",
    "details": [
      {
        "value": 0,
        "description": "no match on required clause ((ngram:fro ngram:rod ngram:odo)~2)",
        "details": [
```

The above is expected since atleast two out of three tokens from frodo should match.

Comment: thanks for the quick and thorough response! And you are correct about rudolpho, i mistyped rodolpho (was a fakerjs generated name:).. I'm going to validate I get the same results with just the ngram query with my index (I suspect so), then try adding in the query against the name field and get back to you. Thanks again!

Comment: Please see the gist above and [**here**](https://gist.github.com/jordancardwell/f954be7eb545cab9d482ff135bbc4860) for explanation of a match query still returning every match with a single matching trigram.  

I'm still looking into it, but honestly the `_explain` results are a bit confusing.